# Cocoa: how to reopen closed window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, delegates, nsview

I make program without nib\xib files. It's simple NSOpengGl window. It's work fine, but when I close window (red button) and want open it again (by click task bar icon) - it does not work.
applicationShouldHandleReopen - does not called.
Here is my code:

```
   @interface OGLView: NSOpenGLView <NSApplicationDelegate,NSWindowDelegate>
   @end

   @implementation OGLView
   -(BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
 {
  printf("bingo");//does not called  
 return YES;
 }

@end
```

and init:

```
....
view = [[OGLView alloc] initWithFrame:glRect pixelFormat:fmt];
[[view openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];

win = [ [NSWindow alloc]
      initWithContentRect: e
       styleMask:
      NSTitledWindowMask
     | NSClosableWindowMask
       |NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
      |  NSResizableWindowMask       
       backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
       defer: YES ];

[win orderFrontRegardless];
[win setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
[win setContentView:view];
[win makeFirstResponder:view];
[win setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
[win setContentView:view];
[view setNeedsDisplay:YES];

[win setDelegate:view ];

[view display];  
[win makeKeyAndOrderFront: view];
...
```

I think applicationShouldHandleReopen does not called because it must called not from NSView object but from delegate. But I'm using

```
[win setDelegate:view ];
```

How can I called this delegate methods?
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

In the application "applicationShouldHandleReopen"  method make your window orderFront

```
 -(BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
 {
    [win makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    return YES;
 }
```

You should call "applicationShouldHandleReopen" method in the app delegate not inside your view.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I call this from delegate? I don't know how to make custom delegate... Please, help - I'm newbie in cocoa((

Comment: Do you want to make your view as App delegate ?.

Comment: Yes,I don't know how to make my custom NSview class as my own custom app delegate.

Comment: You can do like this : [NSApp setDelegate:self]; . So you will receive app delegate notification . But this is not a good approach your view handle these things.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate:view]; works fine!